# Flutter - Google Map custom marker been cut into half with translated source widget

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I need to create a custom marker for the Google's map. I need to align the left border of the custom marker widget with the pointed location which require me to push the widget half width to the right, so I used `FractionalTranslation` for that. Of course I still got a full width source widget after the translation. No problem so far.

The problem happened after converted (`RenderRepaintBoundary`) the widget into marker's icon. The icon lost it's right part, been cut into half.

```
...

class TheState extends State<TheScreen>{

  ...
  GlobalKey<MarkState> globalkey = GlobalKey<MarkState>();
  Set<Marker> marks = Set();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    ...
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      body : Stack(
        children : [
          Mark(globalkey), 
          GoogleMap(
            ...
            markers : marks,
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }

  ...
    setState((){
      marks.clear();
      marks.add(Marker(
        ... 
        icon : await convert(gk)
      ));
    });
  ...

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> convert(GlobalKey gk) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = gk.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio : 2);
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());
  }
}

...

class MarkState extends State<Mark>{
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => RepaintBoundary(
    child : FractionalTranslation(
      translation : Offset(0.5, 0),
      child : ...
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround not really an answer for my question. I post here as it solved my problem for now but I still looking for a reason why the `FractionalTranslation` resulting the issue like in the question.

Instead of using `FractionalTranslation`, I simply doubled the width of the widget with a transparent padding to the left, so that'll push the widget actual border to the middle.

But I also had to `Transform.scale(scale : 0.5)` the widget to avoid overflow rendering.

I get the original size back by passing the `pixelRatio` to the `BitmapDescriptor`.

```
BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes((await (await (globalkey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary).toImage(pixelRatio : 2)).toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))!.buffer.asUint8List());
```